# How to exclude symmetric records

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Let T is table T (field1, field2) with sample data

```
(1, 2) // first part
(3, 4)
(5, 6)
....
(2, 1) // second part
(4, 3)
(6, 5)
```

How to exclude second part of records where `second.field2 = first.field1 and second.field1 = first.field2`?

Comment: `select * from t where field1 < field2;` is the standard symmetry-breaker.

Comment: use `second.field1<first.field2` or `second.field1>first.field2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just You could use `least` and `greatest` to order the two fields and use the `distinct` operator to remove duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(field1, field2), GREATEST(field1, field2)
FROM   t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM ztable t
WHERE field1 <= field2
OR NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM ztable x
    WHERE x.field1 = t.field2 AND x.field2 = t.field1
    );
```

This will give only the *(f1 <= f2)* record if both versions exist, or the actual record if only one version exists.